# How to turn a Linux application in C/C++ into a Desktop Environment for a Linux distro?

Tags: c, linux, unix, user-interface

Is it possible to write an program in C/C++ and then turn that into a Linux Desktop Environment?
I want to take an program, and then be able to boot into my Linux distro and just see that.

Say I have a Linux program which is a window containing "Hello World" on a white background.
How can I make that program into a Linux Desktop Environment for a distro, where you boot and just see: `Hello World`, on a white background.

Any ideas? Let me know if that made no sense.

**Edit:** I am not talking about cross-compiling.

Comment: I have to say it:  A "Hello World" desktop environment would be the crappiest UI ever.  :)

Comment: Easiest is probably load it at the end of /etc/rc.local or similar on your distribution of choice. This assumes you don't start some other window manager by default. Alternatively, use the .xsession file on a per user basis and log in one user automatically. This users' .xsession file will contain the stuff you want to load.

Comment: Ummm... Yes?!? I highly suspect that desktop environments like KDE, Gnome, Enlightenment, <insert your favorite here> are generally written in C and/or C++. So it is definitely possible. How to actually write your own though, is a *huge* topic, and probably not very well suited for a forum like this...

Comment: @twalberg He doesn't necessarily need a WM. A lot of single-purpose machines just need to start one full-screen application per X instance. That's a simple request that's easy to fulfil, he just wants to know what plumbing it needs for lightdm/gdm to launch the environment (in this case, it's just a .desktop file in /usr/share/Xsessions).

Comment: @NicholasWilson You may very well be right, but, at least to me, a "Linux Desktop Environment" is somewhat more than an exclusive-access kiosk-type application, and would hardly qualify for that title without (at least) a window manager. So, perhaps the question could have been worded a little more clearly...

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to be modifying rc files. Use your distro's existing mechanism for controlling lightdm/gdm/other and starting X. You want to create a new X session type by writing an Xsession file, so that your DE shows up as another DE alongside KDE and GNOME. Put your script in `/usr/share/xsessions` (and see the existing examples there).

Answer (score 1):

You either want to

- create a boot loader, or
- you want to replace the 'shell'.

  This would be governed by per-user or global `xinit` and `Xsession` files.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement: Run your own GUI application automatically, after system starts up. Am I right?

Here is what I have done with such requirement (I succefully made it working under Slackware):

1. Allow auto-login after system boot
2. Make a customizable Window Manager to be default WM lauchedby startx (I use FVWM)
3. Configure WM to launch your application after it starts up, and disable unneeded shortcut keys
4. Edit user's startup script (such as .bashrc or .bash_profile) to startx

Now, you can reboot to see whether it works.